# c# int error int Tamanho = textBox3.Text;

Tags: c#

```
int Tamanho = textBox3; // error line <<<
        string senha = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < Tamanho; i++)
```

I cannot put `= TextBox3` .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are attempting to read the value from a text box and put it into an integer. The problem with this is that the .Text property of textBox3 is a string. You need to parse this before you can use it as an int. Take a look at my example below.

```
int Tamanho = 0;
if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out Tamanho) == false) {
  // You should handle the event that the text is not a number here ...
}
string senha = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < Tamanho; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the Text property from `textBox3` by using `textBox3.Text`

And then parse it to int using:

If textBox3.Text contain only a valid int numbers

```
int Tamanho = int.Parse(textBox3.Text)
```

Otherwise

```
if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out Tamanho)) {
    // Only execute of it can be parse to int
}
```